# Double parse scientific notation without 'E'

Tags: c#, double

There are plenty of answered questions about how to parse a number in scientific notation in C#:

```
Double.Parse("1.234567E-06", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```

But, is there a built in function to parse a number like this without introducing manually a 'E'?

```
2.8095-9
```

EDIT: here is the method to insert an "E" and parse the string to double

```
  private double RecExp(string myString)
    {
        if (myString.Trim() == string.Empty) { return 0; }
        if (myString.Contains('-'))
        {
            if (myString.ToUpper().Contains("E") == false)
            {
                myString= myString.Insert(myString.IndexOf('-'), "E");
            }
        }
        return Double.Parse(myString, NumberStyles.Float);
    }
```

Just as clarification, I wasn't asking for providing this piece of code, I was asking if there *exists* a built in way of doing this.

Comment: No, because this is a custom notation that you made up for the purposes of this question. What's the problem with introducing an "e" or just using a proper notation in the first place?

Comment: See NASTRAN input file to find that notation.

Comment: The format is so unusual that there are good reasons to assume that you are just misinterpreting it.  And it actually represents *two* numbers, strung together without a space.  Caused by a bug in the program that wrote the text, the programmer just never figured that the second number was ever going to be negative.  No, you can't convince .NET to parse it as one number.

Comment: The "second" number is the exponent. It's just a strange way of expressing it.